# Cannot serialize member X of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection because it is an interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an ASMX file that returns a List. I am using EntityFramework and Database First pattern.

I created my EDMX with Visual Studio. I have User, Stock and UserStockRelation tables. The User class looks like below

```
public User()
{
    this.UserStockRelation = new HashSet<UserStockRelation>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<UserStockRelation> UserStockRelation { get; set; }
```

Because of the ICollection, it returns the error I mention in the title. If I convert ICollection to List, it gives the error below...

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<UserStockRelation> to System.Collections.Generic.List<UserStockRelation>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not convert the `ICollection<UserStockRelation>` to a `HashSet<UserStockRelation>` instead of a `List<UserStockRelation>`

Comment: I tried but I am using this in ASMX, and it gives this error System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document